# Email Regex Validator, not allowing "."

Tags: asp.net, regex, email-validation

Hey I have the following Regex Validator

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="email"
                ErrorMessage="Email requires a vaild email address" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

But its not allowing the follow mail e.clear@company.ie , I believe the issue is with the . before the @ symbol, but not sure how to update the regex to reflect this

Comment: The only valid regex for email addresses is [this one](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) as far as I know.

Comment: make use of email regex expresssion which is already there in asp.net regex expression collection

Comment: but any idea how I can update my one \w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)* to allow to the dot "." before the "@" symbol

Comment: If you try to match the e-mail address using the regexp for instance in a unit test you will see that it matches. There is probably some escaping issue when the regexp is read from the XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*
```

This is the default regular expression provided with RegularExpressionValidator. Yours expression have a ' after 8th char. It seems to be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

i think its working for e.clear@company.ie. But you are not given the validation group.